# Why did black swans to evolve black colouring?

Tags: evolution, ornithology

What environmental factor caused black swans, which are native in Western Australia, to evolve black feathers ? Note swans are either black or white, there are no brown or grey colurings, which can be commonly found in various geese and duck spieces.

Comment: Because somewhere, sometime in the distant Australian past, either it helped them hide from, or deter, predators and/or helped them hide from prey increasing their chances of feeding and/or made them attractive to others and/or somehow a gene linked to color conferred some quality which increased their chance of survival. You missed the Black Necked Swan.

Comment: Also, is there any disadvantage in having black feather? Because characteristics like "the color of something" may just appear by simple point mutation and stay if not counterselected. Often they have a social effect, for example it's easier to recognize your pups if they have a different color.